# Command to get milliseconds by static time given

Tags: bash, shell, time

I found command like this `$(date +%s%3N)` to convert current time to milliseconds, but example I have time like this 2018-25-08 12:00 PM. How to convert it to millisecond in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this command to convert static date to milliseconds

```
date -d 'date -d '08/23/2018 23:59:59' +"%s%3N"
```

Comment: Just saying `date -d '08/23/2018 23:59:59' +%s%3N` would work. The `%3N` part will be filled with "000" anyway.